# I can't load the model using GLTFLoader

Tags: three.js

```
this.loadMyModel = function(){
        const loader2 = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
        // Load a glTF resource
        loader2.load(
            // resource URL
            'Duck.gltf',
            // called when the resource is loaded
            function ( gltf ) {
                //alert('success');
                this.scene.add( gltf.scene );
            })
    };
```

The js files have been included.

I got an error, but I don't know why:

> TypeError:undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this,scene.add')

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your callback function, `this` is not the same as outside of the function. For more information on how `this` works in JS, I'd suggest this article: http://www.digital-web.com/articles/scope_in_javascript/

To fix the issue, you should save a reference to the scene outside the callback:

```
var scene = this.scene;
this.loadMyModel = function () {
  // ...
  loader.load( 'foo.glb', function ( gltf ) {
    scene.add( gltf.scene );
  } );
}
```

Alternatively, using newer JS features like arrow functions will also get around this problem.